# Action event for call ending process in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

I am developing an application in which i want to keep a track an outgoing call and its duration.For example,If a mobile phone user dials a call I used Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.**When he cut the call,what action to implement?.**I referred all tutorials,they suggested that use device call log URI.But i want to do it in broadcastreceiver.Thanks in advance.

```
  public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

       }    

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please post the `adb logcat` output, including the _caused by_ sections of the exception trace.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I can get the dialed number when i run this app.Still no exception i got.I'm asking like action dialing (ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) any other activity for ending the call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Boolean wasnumberdialed=false;
Boolean callpicked=false;

//if dialed below is called
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        wasnumberdialed=true;
}

//if the call is received by the recipient then this is executed and its an 
//outgoing call,(wasnumberdialed is set to true only for outgoing calls) we 
//need to  ignore incoming calls. If wedont check this an incoming call 
//would also execute this.
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK && wasnumberdialed)) {
        //start your timer to count the time of call
        //long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        callpicked=true;
 }

//after the call is disconnected and was received which is an outgoing call below is 
//executed
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE && callpicked)) {
        //end your timer here
        //long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

Log.v("myapp","Total call time is "+TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(end_time-start_time)+" mins);
```